# Showing two sums are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As part of a proof, I need to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2k}{2n-2k+1}\binom{2n}{2k}.$$
I tried Induction but without much success and I really don't know how to approach the problem. Could anybody give me a hint on how I could go about it?

Comment: You just have to prove that in $[1,2n]$ there are as many subsets with an even number of elements as subsets with an odd number of elements. Both sums equal $$ 2^{2n-1} \neq 2^{2n}-1$$ (so I am removing the previous misleading comment by Sonnhard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k} = \sum_{h=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{h}\frac{1^h+(-1)^h}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(1+1)^{2n} = 2^{2n-1} $$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2k}{2n-2k+1}\binom{2n}{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}=\sum_{h=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{h}\frac{1^h-(-1)^h}{2}=\text{same thing}.$$

Comment: Nice work, as usual.